# Prisma doesn't know which type to use in an nested update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, prisma

So I have a prisma schema with user and data that has an array

```
type AkPastRecruitment {
  date    Int
  tags    String[]
  picked  String[]
  outcome String?
  time    Float
}

type AkHistory {
  recruitments AkPastRecruitment[]
}

model akdata {
  id       String      @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  history  AkHistory?

  // relations
  dataRelation users? @relation("dR", fields: [id], references: [dataId])
}

model users {
  id       String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  username String  @unique
  pass     String  @default("password") @map("_q")
  dataId   String? @unique @db.ObjectId

  //relations
  dR akdata? @relation("dR")
}
```

Whenever I try to update it via relation it errors out

The update

```js
/* type of data.history: 
{
    date: number;
    tags: string[];
    picked: string[];
    outcome: string | null;
    time: number;
}[] | undefined
*/
    const recruitments:
        | Prisma.Enumerable<Prisma.AkPastRecruitmentCreateInput>
        | undefined = data.history ? [...data.history] : data.history;

    const history: Prisma.AkHistoryCreateInput | null = data.history
        ? {
              recruitments,
          }
        : null;

    await prismaClient.users.update({
        where: { username: data.username },
        data: {
            dR: {
                update: {
                    history
                },
            },
        },
    });
```

But it throws error:

```
Unknown arg `recruitments` in data.dR.update.history.recruitments for type AkHistoryNullableUpdateEnvelopeInput. Available args:

type AkHistoryNullableUpdateEnvelopeInput {
  set?: AkHistoryCreateInput | Null
  upsert?: AkHistoryUpsertInput
  unset?: Boolean
}
```

But when I change it into AkHistoryNullableUpdateEnvelopeInput

```js
const recruitments:
    | Prisma.Enumerable<Prisma.AkPastRecruitmentCreateInput>
    | undefined = data.history ? [...data.history] : data.history;

const history: Prisma.AkHistoryNullableUpdateEnvelopeInput | null =
    data.history
        ? {
                set: {
                    recruitments,
                },
            }
        : null;

await prismaClient.users.update({
    where: { username: data.username },
    data: {
        dR: {
            update: {
                history
            },
        },
    },
});
```

It throws an error that tells me to go back to the previous way with AkHistoryCreate

```
Unknown arg `set` in data.dR.update.history.set for type AkHistoryCreateInput. Did you mean `select`? Available args:
type AkHistoryCreateInput {
  recruitments?: AkPastRecruitmentCreateInput | List<AkPastRecruitmentCreateInput>
}
```

How do you update an array inside the relation in prisma?

I was searching the docs but couldn't find it anywhere and these errors don't help at all.